# Test iPhone app made in flex on iPhone 3GS?

Tags: ios, apache-flex

I have built an app in Adobe Flex (4.5) and it works well on Android, but i need to test it on an iDevice. I have an iPhone 3GS available, and I have made a provisioning profile with it and certified it through the proper Apple channels, but trying to install the app to the phone through iTunes results in an error (the same one you get when trying to install non-market apps), and I can't find a way to import it into xCode.

NOTE: I developed the app on a PC in Flex, but have a MacBook Pro available for testing.

Is there any way to test my app or am I out of luck?

Comment: You should be able to develop an test w/o a Mac.  A Mac is only needed for uploading to the Apple Store.  But, I haven't done this myself; so I'm not sure what the resolution for your specific error might be.

Comment: @www.Flextras.com So is there no way of avoiding the purchase of a mac when developing Flex applications on a PC for the iPhone?

Comment: @Phil, i can honestly say in my experience that it's almost unavoidable. i've had to borrow my girlfriends Mac for several days now, and i'm resorting to making a virtual machine on my Linux laptop so i can do this stuff. i've called Apple several times for support, and they've basically stonewalled me every time as soon as they learn i'm not using a mac.

Comment: ouch... Im going to try and use an emulator and see how that works out. Has that worked for you?

Comment: yeah, flex has an emulator built in. When you're demo'ing for a client though, i like to pretty much stick to actual devices :P

Comment: @jlehenbauer If you want to develop an iOS app; you should be able to do it fine w/o a Mac.  If you wan to release it to the Apple Store, you'll need a Mac  [or at least OSX running in some form of visualization--if that is possible]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a developer version of your iPhone for it to work.  Take a peek at the [Adobe documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/iphone/air_deviphoneapps.pdf).  Look at Page 4 for "Obtaining and working with iPhone developer file".

Comment: THANK YOU!! This is what i've been looking for forever.

Comment: also, with the making of CSR files, i've tried to install openssl a couple times now, and it hangs up in the last little bit every time and never completes the installation. do you have any insight on this?

Comment: can't say I've had that problem.  OpenSSL has installed for me.  Try to reboot maybe?